# RESTful WebServices in without Tomcat (or any other container)

Tags: rest, spring-ws

Is there a way to implement RESTful WebService using Spring 3 (or not) that does not use any web container?

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the RESTful request will arrive over HTTP? So something needs to listen on the appropriate port and dispatch requests off to the service code. Obviously you can write such code, but you are likely to end up with something not very different from a Web Server.

If your objective is to embed this capability in some context then a lighweight container such as Jetty (as proposed by skaffman) seems like an answer - I'd be reluctant to write my own code instead

Using a framework such as JAX-RS makes writing REST services very easy, so if the actual objective is develop RESTful services quickly then I'd be prepared to live with a container that does the work for me.

Comment: REST deeply requires HTTP, as it uses HTTP verbs (GET, POST, etc.) extensively.

Comment: If a request saying GET arrived over some other transport would it then not be RESTful? I'd argue that architecturally the trasnport could be something else.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, yes - the various Spring-WS components are decoupled from the Servlet API.  So you could, in theory, use the webserver built in to the Sun Java6 JRE.

In practice, this would be a lot of extra work. You'd have to bridge the Sun Web Server API to the Spring-WS API.

As an alternative to traditional Servlet containers, I can highly recommend [Embedded Jetty](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty), where your app can start up a lightweight servlet container within itself, and serve Spring-WS from that.